# Find an example of a torsion module $M$ such that $ann(M)=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be an integral domain. Find an example of a torsion $R$-module $M$ such that $ann(M)=0$.

I looked at a proof online that goes as follows:

[image: I looked at a proof online that goes as follows:]

My question is how is one able to conclude that every $\alpha$ in $M$ has a largest component $t$?

Comment: This is part of the definition of a direct sum.  Elements may only have finitely many nonzero components.  Polynomials are a good example: they have only finitely many nonzero terms $a_n x^n$, versus power series, which can be infinite sums.  [Wikipedia gives a good explanation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum)

Comment: Obviously! Haha. Thanks!